# Query one unique ID across three tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to query one unique id value existing within one of three different tables.

The three tables have tiered sets of primary key ids e.g.

```
t1 = 1-9 
t2 = 10-19 
t3 = 20-29
```

These tables are part of an `optgroup` menu and the PK's are used as the select values. It's a multi-select so users can choose up to 3 values—which could all come from one of those tables, or one from each.

Each selection is stored in a separate column, e.g. `value1`, `value2`, `value3` of a target table. If only one value is passed, the other columns are `NULL`.

My problem — I have a CSV file of raw data dumped into a temp table. Each row in the temp table has three existing columns representing these values, but they are currently the string values also found in the three tables, and not the `id`. This data needs to be inserted into another table setup with appropriate FK's that work with the app.

How do I query across the existing three tables, looking for the `id` value of the given string that matches any of the 3 tables, and then do it 2 more times—in the same query—for the remaining "value" columns in the temp table row?

**Edit**

More example data for clarification:

The data from a temp table:

```
temp
+---------+---------+---------+--------+
|  value1 |  value2 |  value3 |   user |
+---------+---------+---------+--------+
| primary |   light |     red |   greg | 
|     red |    blue |    NULL |  sarah |
| neutral |  orange |   green |    tim |
|    dark |    blue |   green |  laura |
+---------+---------+---------+--------+
```

needs to be inserted into another table. The id's for the `valueX` columns exist across three tables:

```
table 1
+---------+---------+
|      id |    name | 
+---------+---------+
|     003 | neutral |
|     004 |    dark |
|     005 |   light |
+---------+---------+


table 2
+---------+---------+
|      id |    name | 
+---------+---------+
|     010 |    blue | 
|     011 |  orange | 
|     012 |     red |
|     013 |   green |
+---------+---------+


table 3
+---------+---------------+
|      id |          name | 
+---------+---------------+
|     020 |       primary |
|     021 | complimentary |
|     022 |     secondary |
+---------+---------------+
```

Other columns from the temp table (`user` in this example) are part of the insert, which populate the target table like so:

```
   target
    +---------+---------+---------+-------+
    |  value1 |  value2 |  value3 |  user |
    +---------+---------+---------+-------+
    |     020 |     005 |     012 |  greg |
    |     012 |     010 |    NULL | sarah |
    |     003 |     011 |     013 |   tim |
    |     004 |     010 |     013 | laura |
    +---------+---------+---------+-------+
```

My closest attempt is able to grab the first column of values, but I'm lost on how to grab the other two, in the same query.

```
INSERT INTO target (user, value1, value2, value3)
SELECT t.user, a.id, X, X
FROM  temp t,  
      (SELECT * FROM table1
       UNION
       SELECT * FROM table2
       UNION    
       SELECT * FROM table3) as a
WHERE a.name = t.value1
AND X = t.value2
AND X = t.value3
```

Trying to solve for X.. I'm pretty out of my element here, but this is closer to illustrating what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can create views, then you can create a union of all the tables and search that one to build your table. Something like:

```
CREATE VIEW all AS
  select * from table1 union
  select * from table2 union
  select * from table3;

SELECT
  (select id from all where name = value1) as value1,
  (select id from all where name = value2) as value2,
  (select id from all where name = value3) as value3,
  user
FROM temp;
```

Comment: This is perfect, and in my particular scenario, allows for the other WHERE.. AND queries still to be made. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.t_name
FROM
    (SELECT id, t1_name AS t_name FROM t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, t2_name AS t_name FROM t2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, t2_name AS t_name FROM t3) a
WHERE a.id IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
```

**Update 1**

After getting some sample data, I think this is the direction you want to go:

```
SELECT a.v1, a.v2, a.v3
FROM
    (SELECT id AS v1, NULL AS v2, NULL AS v3 FROM t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL AS v1, id AS v2, NULL AS v3 FROM t2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL AS v1, NULL AS v2, id AS v3 FROM t3) a
WHERE a.v1 = someId OR a.v2 = someId OR a.v3 = someId
```

Comment: That does the trick, but unfortunately I wasn't clear enough. The above result is a dump of all a.id's, what I'm looking for is columned results by value, e.g. `SELECT value1, value2, value3`, but with the id result.. Don't know if that makes sense.

Comment: @PHPeer See my updated answer. Are we getting on the right path at least?

Comment: Thanks njk. You're dealing with a newbie here, so my apologies! Couldn't quite work out the second approach, but am still fiddling. I've revised my question with a more concrete example of the scenario.